# Unity 5 Can't Get Component (Trying to pull from another class)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I'm making a Terraria-like game, I've been creating the biomes but have been having trouble rendering the chunks. I've put the second code in a "GameMaster" gameobject in the game. And used Gameobject Chunk in the second code to attach a gameobject with the first code. For some reason my GetComponent<>().width; doesn't recognize the ChunkGenerator class. Therefore giving me errors. Anything helps. Thanks. I've attached the two codes below.

```
Here's the first code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChunkGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject DirtTile;
    public GameObject StoneTile;
    public GameObject GrassTile;
    public GameObject SandTile;

    public int heightAddition;

    public int width;
    public float heightMultiplier;

    float worldSeed;

    float playerSpawnBiome;


    public float smoothness;
    public float mountSmooth;

    void Start () {
    //  playerSpawnBiome = Random.Range (-5f, 10f);
    //  if (playerSpawnBiome > 0f) {
    //      GenerateMountainBiome ();
    //  } else if ((playerSpawnBiome > 0f) && (playerSpawnBiome <= 5f)) {
            GeneratePlainsBiome ();
    //  } else {
    //      GenerateSandBiome ();
    //  }

    }
    public void GeneratePlainsBiome() {
        worldSeed = Random.Range (-10000f, 10000f);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
        {
            int h = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise (worldSeed, (i + transform.position.x / smoothness) * heightMultiplier) + heightAddition);
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                GameObject selectedTile;
                if (j < h - 3) {
                    selectedTile = StoneTile;
                } else if (j < h - 1) {
                    selectedTile = DirtTile;
                } else {
                    selectedTile = GrassTile;
                }
                GameObject newTile = Instantiate (selectedTile, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                newTile.transform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;
                newTile.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (i, j);
            }
    }
    }
    public void GenerateSandBiome() {
        worldSeed = Random.Range (-10000f, 10000f);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
        {
            int h = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise (worldSeed, (i / smoothness) * heightMultiplier) + heightAddition);
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                GameObject selectedTile;
                if (j < h - 3) {
                    selectedTile = StoneTile;
                } else if (j < h - 1) {
                    selectedTile = SandTile;
                } else {
                    selectedTile = SandTile;
                }
                Instantiate (selectedTile, new Vector3(i, j), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }

    public void GenerateMountainBiome() {
        worldSeed = Random.Range (-10000f, 10000f);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
        {
            int h = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise (worldSeed, (i / 3f) * mountSmooth) * heightMultiplier) + heightAddition;
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                GameObject selectedTile;
                if (j < h - 3) {
                    selectedTile = StoneTile;
                } else if (j < h - 1) {
                    selectedTile = DirtTile;
                } else {
                    selectedTile = GrassTile;
                }
                Instantiate (selectedTile, new Vector3(i, j), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the second Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChunkGenerators : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject chunk;
    int chunkWidth;
    public int numChunks;
    float seed;

    void Start() {
        chunkWidth = chunk.GetComponent<ChunkGenerator> ().width;
        seed = Random.Range (-1000000f, 1000000f);
        Generate ();
    }

    public void Generate() {
        int lastX = -chunkWidth;
        for (int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
            GameObject newChunk = Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (lastX + chunkWidth, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            newChunk.GetComponent<ChunkGenerator> ().seed = seed;
            lastX += chunkWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error log in the console, thanks.

Comment: @JackLeahy Assets/ChunkGenerators.cs(22,45): error CS1061: Type `ChunkGenerator' does not contain a definition for `seed' and no extension method `seed' of type `ChunkGenerator' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Try making the `seed` variable in the `ChunkGenerators` function **public**.

Comment: @JackLeahy Yeah same error message, for some reason it doesn't recognize the class ChunkGenerator

Comment: Figured it out, making an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are referencing the wrong script. You're mistakingly referencing `ChunkGenerator` instead of `ChunkGenerators`.

**Change:**

`newChunk.GetComponent<ChunkGenerator> ().seed = seed;`

**to**

`newChunk.GetComponent<ChunkGenerators> ().seed = seed;`

Comment: No problem. Can you please accept my answer, thanks.